# Разьединить двух братьев из одного элемента обратно в два братских

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

```js
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Здравствуйте, есть такая структура html, к примеру два **div'a** в каждом по два `ul` , при разрешении < 681 px, **два** `ul` в первом `div` сливаются **в один** `ul` но второго `div` не должно это касаться, он должен быть в пассивном состоянии, и наоборот.

При разрешении > 680 , в **активном div** один `ul` опять становился в начальное положение по **два** `ul`, без потери дочерних элементов. Нужно решить задание _без применения дополнительных классов элементам.

Comment: Это вам надо реализовать в динамике? В смысле браузер будут тянуть мышей? Или это просто брейкпоинты для разных устройств?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin совершенно верно, это нужно реализовать брейкпоинты для разных устройство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$(window).resize()** - слушает любое изменение окна браузера.

**$(window).width()** - возвращает ширину окна браузера. Используйте его для построения элементов под разные устройства:

```js
var list = $("ul.siblings:first").parent().html(); // записываем исходную разметку списков

$(window).resize(function() {

    console.clear();
    console.log($(window).width());

    if($(window).width() < 500) { // замените на ваш breakpoint
    
        if($("ul.siblings").length > 1) { 
            console.log("list combined");
            $('ul.siblings').not(':first').remove()
           .children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
        }

    } else {
     
        if($("ul.siblings").length <= 1) {
            console.log("list splited");
            $('ul.siblings').parent().html(list);
        }
    
    }

})
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: не работает, попробуйте сами

Comment: Вы если пробуете прямо тут, в коде ответа, то поменяйте контрольную точку с 680 (это я для вас написал) на, например, 300. Т.к. вьюпорт в примере меньше, чем весь ваш экран. Ответы всегда проверяются перед размещением. Кроме, разве что, тривиальных. Или скопируйте отсюда в ваш рабочий код и проверяйте там.

Comment: Тут (в ответе) вьюпорт примера не меняет ширину при изменении ширины браузера. Поэтому ответы об изменении поведения при измепнении разрешений лучше тестировать на живом проекте. Или использовать функцию "Копировать код в ответ". Тогда при редактировании примера можно наблюдать эффект.

Comment: не работает хоть ты тресни, даже на $(window).width() < 100, в рабочем коде тоже не работает, я не хочу сказать что вы написали плохой код, просто не работает, у Вас как я понял работает правильно

Comment: проверял на https://jsfiddle.net/pbfh6bzx/ , можете сами посмотреть, что структура меняется не динамически, а только после обновления html

Comment: @Владимир Владимирович "совершенно верно, это нужно реализовать брейкпоинты для разных устройство" - это ведь вы написали в комменте к вашему вопросу? Вот такой и ответ. А вопрос всё-таки про динамическое изменение поведения?

Comment: Да, все таки про динамическое, и посмотрите условие пожалуйста, я его обновил.

Comment: @Владимир Владимирович - тестируйте.

Comment: посмотрите в консоли , что делает с родителями , ваша функция, не  красиво так с родителями поступать)) https://jsfiddle.net/encaru2e/

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document-fragment' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'. - это? Такое очевидно происходит потому, что песоченица (iframe -> document).

Comment: нет, Ваша функция удаляет сначала div в который обернуты ul, а потом тэг боди

Comment: гг, могём) поправил)

Comment: опять не работает, завтра уже зайду и на свежую голову посмотрю, спокойной ночи

Comment: А вы из спалаха?Или сами научились ?

Comment: не понял "из спалаха" ?

Comment: в Харькове есть компания которая занимается преподованием курсов  'спалах'

Comment: Нет) Я из сам научился)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно второму `ul` дать дочерним элементам определенный класс, что бы после объединении смогли узнать какие элементы принадлежат второму `ul`.

```
<div>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li class="ul_2">3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ul_2">4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Ну а сейчас когда вы захотите обратно разделить на 2 `ul`. Уже можете сделать так.

```
$('ul.siblings').after('<ul class="siblings"></ul>');
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').append($('.ul_2'));
```

Ну вот и второй вариант с подсчетом дочерних элементов.

```
var first_childs = $('ul.siblings:first-child').children('li').length;
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

И здесь уже разделение.

```
$('ul.siblings').after('<ul class="siblings"></ul>');
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').append($('ul.siblings>li:nth-child(n+'+first_childs+')'));
```

Comment: хороший способ, но мне нужен метод без добавления дополнительных классов

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович Можно просто в тот момент когда объединяете `ul` дать классы, а в обратном действии удалить их. Ну как бы темповые классы.

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович Ну а если и это не по душе, то перед тем как объединить `ul`. Посчитайте сколько дочерей у первого. Что бы смогли потом разделить их по нужным кускам.(Брать только тех дочерей которые после считанных первого).

Comment: Можете расписать ваш последний ответ с счётом дочерей первого ul, через сниппет пожалуйста, и я отмечу как раз Ваш ответ за самый валидный